# Django: test url regex in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a same template that is used for different urls (in this case: `/create/` and `/edit/[PK of an item]` , named "create" and "edit" in the url.py).

I would like to show different things in my template depending if I'm on /edit/ or /create/.

How can I check this ?
`{% if '/create' in request.path %}` works, but I'd like to use a url tag (or equivalent, to not have it "hard coded").
What I would like to do looks like (in pseudo code - this doesn't work) `{% if request.path in url create %} XXX {% endif %}`.

Should I make all the necessary tests in the views.py, send a variable about it in the context, test on this variable in the template? In my case it seems a bit heavy for a simple url test ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say go for making two views if it's a significant difference (different form, etc.) - eliminates url logic in templates entirely, and no real 'test' needed either - don't have to check request.path/pass url/etc.

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^create/$', create),
    (r'^edit$', edit),
)
```

**views**

```
def create(request):
    text = "Create something"
    return render_to_response('same-template.html', {'text': text}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)

def edit(request):
    text = "Edit something"
    return render_to_response('same-template.html', {'text': text}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

**template**

```
{% text %}
```

Can also pass multiple changes easily with a list this way too:

**views**

```
def create(request):
    data = []
    data['text'] = "Create something"
    data['form'] = CreateForm()
    return render_to_response('same-template.html', {'data': data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)

def edit(request):
    data = []
    data['text'] = "Edit something"
    data['form'] = EditForm()
    return render_to_response('same-template.html', {'data': data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

**template**

```
{% data.text %}
{% data.form %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set a [url with a as](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url) value.

```
{% url 'some-url-name' arg arg2 as the_url %}

{% if the_url in request.path %}
```

Comment: JamesO, thanks for your answer but : my "edit" url is not a fixed url but a regex: `url(r"^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$", MyEditView.as_view(), name=edit)`. Is there a way I can use this way of doing (with a `with`) ?

Comment: Deprecated since Django 1.8 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#s-url

Comment: @ChemicalProgrammer, cheers, to clarfy, its the dotted path that has been depreciated not the 'as', which is the answer I was suggesting, will edit.

Comment: @JameO Yes, you're right. My comment possibly produce misunderstanding. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Either you do it in a view, or write a template tag.

Looking on django snippets, this one looks nice: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1531/